# what methods are available on something of type Object #<Text>

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm still befuddled by the NodeList object in Mootools, and I'm hoping someone can help clarify.

I'm making a simple HTML request using Request.HTML. Here's the code:

```
var req = new Request.HTML({
  url: my_url,
  onSuccess: function(response) { alert(response) }
});
req.send();
```

On the server side, I'm just rendering some text ("here's a response", specifically). The alert shows "[oject NodeList]", and I'm wondering what methods I can call on it to get the alert to show "here's a response".

I know that `alert(response[0])` shows "[object Text]". I also figured out that if I put a break line right in the middle of my onSuccess function and type (in the console) response[0] + enter, it show's my "here's a response" text. I just can't figure out how to get the alert to show "here's a response"....

Thanks

Comment: `console.log(this.response);` will show you the response property of the request object as well - some of which is a html collection, the respose tree, the raw html and the parsed javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [mootools docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.HTML):

```
onSuccess(responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML, responseJavaScript)
```

looks like you want the third argument in the onSuccess callback function.  so back to your example:

```
var req = new Request.HTML({
  url: my_url,
  onSuccess: function(responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML) {
    alert(responseHTML)
  }
});
req.send();
```